# Huge contacts storage in galaxy 4

Tags: contacts, storage

In my galaxy for some reason my contacts storage grow to almost 6Gb (should be some sync problem.) I dont have SD . I deleted all the photos but still grow by itself and cannot open in the phone. How can I fixed? 
Regards
Ricardo

Comment: I have a similar problem on an "LG Viper 4G LTE" running Android 4.0.4 ,,, "Contacts Storage" takes up 920 MB for date (and 0 for app), whihc is more than half of the phone's internal storage. I have maybe a couple hundred contacts, how is it using more than 1MB per contact? Is there a setting I can change to shrink that?